# Machine Learning Feature Columns

Tags: python

I'm trying to wrap my head around the whole feature column thing.  I can build the Iris training model etc with Keras but I want to understand a little more.

What I'm having trouble is with the "Feature_Column" aspect.  For example lets say my data set looks like:

```
 Length     Width     Weight     Label
 1.5        2         .07         1
 1          5         .09         3
 3          6         .19         4
```

I don't get a Feature "Column" as the the "Row" is the example isn't it?  So when I read about a Feature Column what do they mean by that?

From what I can see it's a Feature Row no?  [1.5, 2, .07] = 1 <= that's a Row of Features with a Label 1

I don't know I'm just confused :).  Anyone willing to explain what a Feature Column is when they Transform the data for a feature column?

Comment: You are right about each row being a saperate instance of the data. The feature column is just a column in the above data. You don't actually pass a column to the model, but the row, as you pointed out. But if you want to exclude a certain feature from the data, what do you do? drop that column from the dataset, right? Well, you just dropped a feature column. Just a name, for a column consisting of value of a feature for all independent instances. Useless in itself, but named for ease of data handling.

Comment: @dumbPy Thats........also confusing LOL.  Okay I get dropping the column for the Target you are trying to predict.  But are you saying its like a a new column
FeaturesColumn
[height, width, length...]

Am I understanding that right?  In that it's just a "new" column with the "entire row" as it's value?

Comment: If say you have r=200 data points, each data point being a row. Each row consists of f features, here say f=3 for height, Width, Length. If you take a Feature Column, it would be of shape (r,1), that is, each value in that feature column is the value of that feature for different (200) rows

Comment: @dumbPy thanks for taking the time...I appreciate it.  I get the Column is a Feature Column...I'm trying to understand what the mean when they are creating a "Feature Column"?
`feature_name = "flower_features"
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, 
                                                    shape=[4])]` like that's a new column of the 4 features length,width,height,etc etc...but why are they transposing a row to a column?  Or am I COMPLETELY missing this...I feel stupid.

Comment: @dumbPy I'm working on an image to explain my thoughts sorry...I feel a picture might explain my complete lack of understanding.

Comment: They are not transposing anything. shape=[4] means there are 4 columns in this "flower_features" named feature column(s)

Comment: @dumpPy Thank you very much for explaining things.  I think I get it all now.